# Set annotation @XMLTransient if id==1

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb

I have class that represents users. Users are divided into two groups with different id.
Could i make something like "`if statement`", so `if (id==1)` set annotation on field `@XMLTransient`

Or the only one way to do this is to create two separate classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, annotations are purely compile-time constructs, you can't do that. You'll need to refactor your class model to handle this.